# CouchBase Lite who to use setExpirationDate() method

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I am usign `CouchBase lite 1.4` in Android.
I want to remove documents locally after a time, let´s says 15 minutes. I haven been reading that we can [remove documents locally](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-remove-documents-from-local-database-as-well-as-all-mobile-clients/9757/13) using the `setExpirationDate()` method

So what I am doing is:

```
public String createOrUpdateDocument(String jsonDocument) {

        Document d = null;
        String res = null;
        HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) GSONParser.getInstance()
                .fromJson(jsonDocument, HashMap.class);
        if (map.get("_id") != null) {
            //update
            try {
                d = load((String) map.get("_id"));  
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else {
            d = work.createDocument();
            Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(date);
            c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
            Date expiration = c.getTime();
            d.setExpirationDate(expiration);
        }
        if (d != null) {
            try {
                Revision r = d.putProperties(map);
                map.put("_id", r.getDocument().getId());
                map.put("_rev", r.getDocument().getCurrentRevisionId());
                res = GSONParser.getInstance().toJson(map);
            } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {}
        }
        return res;
    }
```

In the other hand I have a list with all the documents I have so what I am doing in order to get a the list with all the documents is:

```
public static List<Object> getWorkDocumentListByTypeAndCompany(String type, Long idCompany){
        if (idCompany == null){
            return getWorkDocumentListByType(type);
        }
        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
        View byIdCompany = CouchbaseManager.getInstance().getWorkdocbytypecompany();
        Query q = byIdCompany.createQuery();
        q.setMapOnly(true);
        q.setStartKey(Arrays.asList(type, idCompany));
        q.setEndKey(Arrays.asList(type, idCompany));
        try {
            QueryEnumerator r = q.run();
            for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = r; it.hasNext(); ) {
                QueryRow row = it.next();
                String jsonValue = GSONParser.getInstance().toJson(row.getValue());
                l.add(getFromJSONValue(type, jsonValue));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return l;
    }
```

where

> .getWorkdocbytypecompany()

is:

```
 workdocbytypecompany = work.getView("work_doc_bytypecompany");
        workdocbytypecompany.setMap(new Mapper() {
            @Override
            public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                if (!document.containsKey("ismaster") && document.containsKey("type") && document.containsKey("company")) {
                    List<Object> key = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    HashMap<String, Object> company = (HashMap<String, Object>)document.get("company");
                    Object idcompany = company.get("id");
                    key.add(document.get("type"));
                    key.add(idcompany == null ? null : new Double(idcompany.toString()).longValue());
                    emitter.emit(key, document);
                }
            }
        },"1.2");
```

But it does not work, the document is not removed, no errors got, no info
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you determining the doc is not removed, and how long are you waiting?  Expiration can take a short amount of time beyond the time set.  Also, is the doc getting modified anywhere else and resynced back?

Comment: I have a list with all the documents I have in local. the device I am using for test does not have internet connection (is turned off) so resynced back is not possible

Comment: How are you generating the list?  Trying to figure out if this is expected behavior or a bug.  How long after the expiration time do you wait to check for the document?

Comment: @Hod sorry for my delay, I have added extra information to my question. Hope it can be useful.

Comment: In general, you don't want to emit the whole document in a map.  It makes the View index overly large.  Since you always get the document ID for free with a query, it's considered best practice to use that to retrieve the whole doc if you need it.  I'm not sure if that's connected to the problem though.  You might try taking that out (so emit (key, null) and retrieve documents).  I will try to look at it further, but wanted to give that suggestion.

Comment: thanks Hod, in fact the app takes a lot of time to show results when I call to getWorkdocbytypecompany() I am going to it see what I can do thanks a lot

Comment: Hello Hod could ypu please  provide me a url where I can see an example about what are you talking about ( I mean ... it's considered best practice to use that to retrieve the whole doc if you need it....) thanks a lot

Comment: So is  better this :  emitter.emit(key, null);    sorry  I dont get what you mean

Comment: I looked for an example, but didn't find one.  It is in the documentation.  But yes, the call would be `emiiter.emit(key, null);`.  You can `getDocumentId()` on each QueryRow from your query results.  Use that to get the document through a key/value lookup.